# Distinguishing between Click and DoubleClick events in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I currently have a NotifyIcon as part of a Windows Form application.  I would like to have the form show/hide on a double click of the icon and show a balloon tip when single clicked.  I have the two functionalities working separately, but I can't find a way to have the app distinguish between a single click and double click. Right now, it treats a double click as two clicks.

Is there a way to block the single click event if there is a second click detected?

Comment: There is a mouse doubleclick event in win form apps! You can have two event, one for mouse click and other for mouse doubleclick and handle separate logic there.

Comment: That's precisely what I am doing right now, but the click event handler is firing even when I double click.

Comment: Is this just in debug mode or even in run mode? If this is in debug mode and you have a breakpoint set in the click event, then the debugger will not wait for your double click. If that is the case then try removing the breakpoint from click event and just set it in the double click event

Comment: It can be achieved by handling the MouseDown event and using a timer. Here is an article about it: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: With the notify icon on Windows 10 I can't get anything but click to work.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the suggested handling of `MouseClick` event doesn't work for `NotifyIcon` class - in my tests `e.MouseClicks` is always 0, which also can be seen from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NotifyIcon.cs,833).

The relatively simple way I see is to delay the processing of the `Click` event by using a form level flag, `async` handler and `Task.Delay` :

```
bool clicked;

private async void OnNotifyIconClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clicked) return;
    clicked = true;
    await Task.Delay(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);
    if (!clicked) return;
    clicked = false;
    // Process Click...
}

private void OnNotifyIconDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clicked = false;
    // Process Double Click...
}
```

The only drawback is that in my environment the processing of the `Click` is delayed by half second (`DoubleClickTime` is 500 ms).

Comment: Simple, elegant and effective solution.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 different kinds of events.

Click/DoubleClick

MouseClick / MouseDoubleClick

The first 2 only pass in EventArgs whereas the second pass in a MouseEventArgs which will likely allow you additional information to determine whether or not the event is a double click.

so you could do something like;

```
obj.MouseClick+= MouseClick;
obj.MouseDoubleClick += MouseClick;
// some stuff

private void MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Clicks == 2) { // handle double click }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to register a `Click` event and then handle single and double clicks from it.

```
    int clickCount;
    async void NotifyIcon_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        if( clickCount > 0 ) {
            clickCount = 2;
            return;
        }
        clickCount = 1;
        await Task.Delay( SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime );

        if( clickCount == 1 ) {
            // Process single click ...
        } else if( clickCount == 2 ) {
            // Process double click ...
        }
        clickCount = 0;
    }
```