# mouse click event fires before mouse double click event on notifyicon winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Using my notify icon my function for mouse click and double click event are entirely different
Mouse click event - will open a form
Doouble click event - will open a folder

Mouse click event do its job but when fire the double click event, it still trigger the mouse click event by which my form still show on double click.

Actual result on double click: opens the folder and opens the form
Expected result on double click: opens the folder

I already close the form on click but still show for a split second before hiding since the mouse click event is fired first before double click event.

```
  private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //opens folder function

            //close widget on double click
            if (widgetForm != null)
                widgetForm.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to avoid click when I want double click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376012/how-to-avoid-click-when-i-want-double-click)

Comment: Why don't you move these two distinct functionalities to two distinct selectors of the ContextMenu of your NotifyIcon?

Comment: [How to distinguish between clicks and double-clicks (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-mouse/how-to-distinguish-between-clicks-and-double-clicks)

Comment: @Jimi i can't use context menu since the functionality are all determined by others

Comment: **Suggestion:** handle the `MouseClick` event only in combination with the [Control.ModifierKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue). Open the folder `if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)`, otherwise show the form.

Comment: @dr.null i can't change the intended functionality

Comment: Then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184040/distinguishing-between-click-and-doubleclick-events-in-c-sharp). Jimi's suggestion in action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code I wrote for `wpf` also works with a slight change in `winforms`.

```
DispatcherTimer timer;
int clickCount = 0;
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   timer = new DispatcherTimer();
   timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
   timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
}

private void MyButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   clickCount++;
   timer.Start();
}
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    if (clickCount >= 2)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("doubleclick");
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("click");
    }
    clickCount = 0;
}
```

for winforms:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer;
int clickCount = 0;
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
   timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
   //SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime default is 500 Milliseconds
   timer.Interval = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;
   //or
   timer.Interval = 200;
}

private void myButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   clickCount++;
   timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    if (clickCount >= 2)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("doubleclick");
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("click");
    }
    clickCount = 0;       
}
```

With the code I mentioned in the `wpf` example, you can change `SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime` to your desired time

Comment: Could you post the code necessary to handle this in WinForms (which of course doesn't use a `DispatcherTimer` and doesn't have a `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event)? Also, take a look at `SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize` and `SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime`.

Comment: @Jimi the `DispatcherTimer` can be replaced with a `Timer` control on the Form of a Winform app or one in memory.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson With an Interval of 1 millisecond?

Comment: Yes, the Timer Elapsed property works in milliseconds, so set it to 1

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson You mean a Timer **Component** which doesn't have an `Elapsed` event but a `Tick` event and has an official resolution of `55ms` and when set below `35ms` causes overlapping events and tends to block the UI? Or a threaded Timer (for this)? -- My comment is related to the wrong Platform, not the use of a Timer. I've posted a link that shows the *official* way to handle this.

Comment: @meysamasadi still triggering the mouse click instead of double click

Comment: I thoroughly tested the code and it worked perfectly. You delete event click and double click and use only this code. If it does not work, enter your code snippet in your question for me to check . And I changed the code a little bit. Make sure it matches your code

Answer (score 3):

i figured out on how to handle this is to add task delay on my mouse click event to wait if it triggers the double click event at the same time.

thank you for the answers!

```
 private bool isSingleClicked;

 private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isSingleClicked = false;
        //double click process
    }
 private async void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       //delay click event to check if it trigger double click event
        isSingleClicked = true;
        await Task.Delay(100);

        //check if it trigger double click event, will not proceed to the next line
        if (!isSingleClicked) return; 

        //process of mouse click
        isSingleClicked = false;
    }
```

Comment: As already mentioned, in the other answer, the interval that determines a double click is a User preference that's referenced by `SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime`, if it's generated within a `SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize`

Comment: Hopefully you are not going to show a modal dialog inside the event handlers.

Comment: @Jimi yes i got some idea on that time delay on your answer also so thank you!

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes i won't. it for open folder and opening of form